# eclipse/STS giving 'no more handles' and 'JVM terminated. Exit code=127' errors

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, swt, sts

```
**the same errors happen in eclipse & STS both(tried 3 versions)
```

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_292

$ uname -a
Linux mypc 4.15.0-142-generic #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Spring Tool Suite 4
Version: 4.16.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202209151144

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

error1: 'JVM terminated. Exit code=127' while right clicking on a project
error2: 'Unhandled event loop exception' while trying to browse a directory for purposes like importing a project, adding JREl's etc

```
**org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles**

eclipse.buildId=4.16.0.202209151144
java.version=17.0.4.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Sun Nov 13 06:47:48 IST 2022
Unhandled event loop exception

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog.error(Dialog.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.openNativeChooserDialog(DirectoryDialog.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.open(DirectoryDialog.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizardPage.lambda$0(MavenImportWizardPage.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4477)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper$ImportAction.run(EmptyWorkspaceHelper.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.helpers.EmptyWorkspaceHelper$1.linkActivated(EmptyWorkspaceHelper.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.lambda$3(AbstractHyperlink.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5796)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4477)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

```
    **JVM terminated. Exit code=127**
/home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038/jre/bin/java
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--illegal-access=permit
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4
-name SpringToolSuite4
--launcher.library /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.600.v20220720-1916/eclipse_11701.so
-startup /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 2f8008
-product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
-vm /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--illegal-access=permit
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-jar /home/cipher/Downloads/sts-4.16.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
```

Comment: How current is your Ubuntu release? Your Java version is a few patch levels behind.

Comment: hi @nitind ! Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS. do you suggest updating to OpenJDK 11 or something?